# Read from a serial port in Swift 4 using ORSSerialPort

Tags: swift, swift4, orsserialport

I've been wanting to make an app that sends instructions over serial to my LED controller. For this to work, I need to read what the controller sends back after sending it a command. I found the following function in `ORSSerialPort`:

```
func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data) {
    // Do things
}
```

However, is there something like `ORSSerialPort.read()`?

Comment: This a delegate method of ORSSerialPort, in order this method to be invoked the object you're using it with should be a delegate. `ORSSerialPort.delegate = self`

Comment: Hi @inokey, thanks for the clarification. I still need a way to read the data using a function like `ORSSerial.read()`.

Comment: As far as I can see from documentation, the only way to receive data from port is through delegate. Meaning as soon as you open the port and it emits an event you will get this data into the method mentioned in your original question. If you're looking for a way to start receiving data it's `serialPort.open()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `ORSSerialPort.read()` is a good idea. I know some other serial libraries are written that way, but the only way for that to work is for `read()` to block (possibly with a timeout) until a byte comes in on the port. Blocking I/O makes it a lot harder to write a good, responsive app, and I want to guide developers using ORSSerialPort away from that approach.

Instead, you should indeed implement `serialPort(_:, didReceive:)` in your `ORSSerialPort` delegate. When data is received by the serial port, that method will be called with the received data and you can do whatever you'd like with it.

That said, if your device communicates using a command/response type protocol (ie. every time you send a command, the device sends some response), you ought to look at ORSSerialPort's request/response API. It allows you to explicitly define the format of expected responses to commands, and ORSSerialPort itself will handle asynchronously waiting for, parsing, and validating responses. See [the documentation](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/wiki/Request-Response-API) for more info about this part of ORSSerialPort. The library also includes a sample project, RequestResponseDemo, that demonstrates using this API. Both Swift and Objective-C versions are included.

Answer (score 1):

The ORSSerialPort library is popular and generally good.  However, I'd found that it didn't work well with TTY serial devices.  This was primarily because of its use of IOKit to discover serial ports -- it would only discover physical devices.

This is likely OK in your case but where you want to test your code but don't want to connect to a physical device, it falls over.  Good code always needs a testing framwork.  So, check out https://github.com/kpishere/POSIXSerialPort for a very simple serial interface API it is just what you need to write and respond to incoming data and also works with physical or virtual devices (as Unix was originally envisoned!).

To your question though, you don't want to call read() directly.  You get into understanding whether or not, "is it a blocking read?"  Then you get into dealing with threads.  Both of the suggested APIs insulate you from that and allow you to think in terms of an event driven model -- this makes for much simpler code.